# Is running GUI apps on server a security issue?

Tags: debian, terminal, security, gui

To edit system files for example `/etc/named/named.conf`, I use:

```
su -
Password:
gedit
```

And then opens and edit above like files, instead of:

```
nano /etc/named/named.conf
```

or:

```
vi /etc/named/named.conf
```

Can this habit of using GUI tools every now and again cause a security problem, especially in **server** environment?

Comment: if you downvote any Question please be good enough to give the specific reason. I respect your opinion but I think I have the right to know **WHAT WENT WRONG**.

Thank you, Downvoters

Comment: This question may be useful to a lot of persons who have stuck with GUIs in deciding were they on right path or it is a time to turn over a new leaf

Comment: The problem is not in a GUI tool, but the X environment. You have to have X server running to handle system calls and stuff. And that posses a possible security issue. I you really can't edit your files with a command editor, than it would be good to run X go to graphical desktop environment, run your precious gedit and then after you stop editing, you should also stop X server...sounds like a LOT of work for just editing a simple file.

Comment: Anyway, you should know how to use a command-line editor in a server. Not always you will have X available.

Comment: @Alko Your advice seems sounds.

Comment: "I think I have the right to know what went wrong" that which you call a right is in fact a courtesy, and your demanding otherwise isn't likely to get you what you seek. People downvote 'round these parts sometimes for no reason at all. But it wasn't me.

Comment: @msw
It is really your courtesy to stop here and drop such a nice advice. thank you

Answer (score 4):

Only in so far as the more code you have running, the more *potential* security holes there are.  Thus at least in theory, you want to minimize the number and complexity of programs you have installed/running.  In practice, as long as you stay on top of security updates, then no, there's no real security reason to avoid a gui on a server.

Of course, it does beg the question as to why you are even using the server on a graphical console rather than via `ssh` in the first place, where you should be quite comfortable using terminal editors.

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason is edit a particular file I think switching to an interactive shell is already a "security issue". It's a point of view though.

Consider that you switch to `root` interactively. Then whatever you run, runs with highest privileges. Now, question is if you do trust applications you are running. Particular application can have a bug which poses a security issue.

My point is, that you want to minimize the stuff you run directly under the `root`. Running X application brings a complexity of whole X stack and if any backdoor or escape can be misused, attacker gains the `root` access. And it's not about the X stack only, it's about any software you run under the `root`. That's also reason why you / we have to be very careful about applications which has `setuid` bit set.

As a solution to your workflow I would offer the `sudoedit` command. You can use it in form of

```
$ sudoedit <file_to_edit>
```

It will try to authenticate / authorize you (as regular `sudo` does) and then it will run your preferred editor (set by `EDITOR` environment variable). Benefit over running as `$ sudo $EDITOR <file_to_edit>` is that the editor itself runs under your original privileges and after you exit it, it will replace the file with the results of your editing. Need to exit the editor to make changes effective might be a bit disruptive though.

Comment: My upvote for `It will try to authenticate / authorize you (as regular sudo does) and then it will run your preferred editor (set by EDITOR environment variable). Benefit over running as $ sudo $EDITOR <file_to_edit> is that the editor itself runs under your original privileges and after you exit it, it will replace the file with the results of your editing. Need to exit the editor to make changes effective might be a bit disruptive though.`

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it. The main reason to get into the habit of text mode tools when you administrate servers is not security, but the ability to do things remotely on low-bandwidth or high-latency connections where GUI applications are impractical.

[image: xkcd 1200]